# Wordpress library / SQL queries to build new frontend?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation I'd like to get rid off. It's been constant work over the past year keeping up with various updates and changes and managing differenet plugins. I've realized I don't need that much functionality and would be perfectly happy with static pages. If I manage to drop the installation I could also speed things up a lot and integrate the content more easily in the rest of our site.

I'm trying to find a PHP or Perl package which I can use to easily query the existing WP DB. Basically, I want to keep the DB and throw away the frontend and backend to WP. Then I just want to add a very minimal layer of PHP or Perl code on top to show the posts in the DB including meta data.

In case there is no package that can make this job easier, is there some concise overview of the SQL queries I will need? I know I can go digging for them in the codebase, but maybe there is someone who has already done this. Googling around didn't immediately turn up useful results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want give a try to jekyll or octopress.

Comment: looks nice, but how do I import or migrate my existing wordpress blog?

Comment: also, I haven't used ruby up to now. I'm mostly a perl/php guy.

Comment: use a little ruby, and there is guide to migrate from wordpress. https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Blog-Migrations